# Subscript Error 9 While Activating the Worksheet in the same Workbook

Tags: excel, vba

Subscript Error 9 while running the following code.
The code is trying to activate the Sheet "Summary Converted", but throws the Error 9. I did try changing the Sheet to other sheet, still the same error.

Please Help Guys!

```
Private Sub HideUnhideConvertedSheets_Click()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
ActiveWorkbook.Unprotect Password:="gato"
ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="GORDO"
If (Range("CP").Value = 0) Then
Sheets("Summary Converted").Visible = True
Sheets("Services Converted").Visible = True
Sheets("Proposal Converted").Visible = True
Sheets("Revenue & Collections Converted").Visible = True
Sheets("Unisys HW SW Converted").Visible = True
Sheets("Third Party Converted").Visible = True
Sheets("Other Services & OC Converted").Visible = True
Sheets("Cash Flow Converted").Visible = True
Sheets("Annual P&L Converted").Visible = True
Sheets("Travel Converted").Visible = True
Sheets("CapEx Converted").Visible = True
Sheets("Summary Converted").Activate
Range("CP").Value = 1
HideUnhideConvertedSheets.Caption = "Hide Converted Sheets"
Else
Sheets("Summary Converted").Visible = False
Sheets("Services Converted").Visible = False
Sheets("Proposal Converted").Visible = False
Sheets("Revenue & Collections Converted").Visible = False
Sheets("Unisys HW SW Converted").Visible = False
Sheets("CapEx Converted").Visible = False
Sheets("Third Party Converted").Visible = False
Sheets("Other Services & OC Converted").Visible = False
Sheets("Cash Flow Converted").Visible = False
Sheets("Annual P&L Converted").Visible = False
Sheets("Travel Converted").Visible = False
Range("CP").Value = 0
HideUnhideConvertedSheets.Caption = "Show Converted Sheets"
End If
ActiveSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=False, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=_True, 
Password:="GORDO"
ActiveWorkbook.Protect Password:="gato"
End Sub
```

Comment: It throws an error on line 17 - Sheets("Summary Converted").Activate

Answer (score 0):

Well, calling `Sheets("Summary Converted").Visible = True` worked fine, so try using it instead of `AcitveWorkbook.Sheets("Summary Converted")` (without `ActiveWorkbook`).

Another suggestions is to use `Worksheets` instead of `Sheets`. Sheets is a collection of worksheets as well as chart sheets.

Comment: I did try that!! Doesn't seem to help.. :(